# Как подсчитать количество паролей, которые удовлетворяют следующим требованиям?

Tags: комбинаторика, информатика

Паролем должны содержать от 3 до 5 символов, среди которых должно быть хотя бы 2 различных, а символами пароля могут быть только десятичные цифры 0-9 и строчные буквы a-z.
**Сколько паролей удовлетворяют перечисленным требованиям?**

Comment: задачу надо решить теоретически или перебором на каком-нибудь языке?

Comment: Только теоретически :) у меня вышло 432, но это кажется мне малым числом, ведь символы и повторяться могут

Comment: 26 букв + 10 цифр = 36 символов. 36**5 = 60466176. Это уже явно сильно больше, чем 432. Да, есть условие на "хотя бы два разных символа", но есть ещё и пароли длиной 4 и длиной 3. Так что что-то вы совсем не так считаете, порядок цифр будет совсем другой.

Comment: их всего 62192340 :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

пароль вида xx...xx, содержащий m символов со словарем в N символов может содержать m^N вариантов

`хотя бы 2 различных` означает, что пароль не может содержать все символы одинаковыми, таких вариантов соответственно N

для цифр и букв имеем словарь в 36 символов

итого

X = 3^36 - 36 + 4^36 - 36 + 5^36 - 36 = 62192340 вариантов